# Capture output of inotifywait in bash

Tags: bash, inotifywait

How can i capture the output of inotifywait in this instance, it is driving me crazy.

Here is my code:

```
 while inotifywait -q -e  create,delete --format '%T %:e "%f"' --timefmt '%d/%m/%y %H:%M'  "$DIR"
    do
       echo -e "$line" >> /mnt/pidrive1/Digital_Signage/log/"$hostname"_sync.log
       echo -e "Folder contents:" $file_number "files in total: " $folder_list  >> /mnt/pidrive1/Digital_Signage/log/"$hostname"_sync.log
    done
```

Comment: What is not working here?

Comment: I am not capturing the $@ in the file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A much simpler way to achieve what you want would be:

```
while inotifywait <whaveter> >> sync.log
do
   # Nothing
done
```

If you need to do extra stuff to your output you can say:

```
while out=$(inotifywait <whaveter>)
do
    # Stuff
    # Just use $out normally
done
```

Comment: I would like to also insert more code in the while loop, you code will not let me do this, see edited code

Comment: @Ossama I added a version that allows you to capture the output.